# Is there an equivalent for 'php://output' in C#?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to download a file instead of save it. Working with php I did just that:

```
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

That was when I was working with PHPExcel. I don't know if you can do something similar in C#.

> php://output is a write-only stream that allows you to write to the output buffer mechanism in the same way as print and echo.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are looking for a way that you avoid writing data on a disk. If I am correct then you should look into [System.IO.MemoryStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx). Simply put, it basically writes data to memory instead of disk.

Answer (score 0):

you can try returning a FileResult in your action